# How to position a line the whole width of a page on a line of text, but not over text?

Tags: inline, line, horizontal

I am in the midst of creating my own custom latex class for a CV layout and am wondering how to do so. Here is a picture of what I'm talking about that I created in a word document:

[image]

Specifically, how the title Education is formatted. Is there a way to wrap a horizontal vertically centered line in a line of text, spanning the whole page/body margins, but not over the text/word that resides in the same line that it will exist in? (Also, if possible the line length will adapt since the titles can be of different lengths, i.e. W O R K, S K I L L S)

Thanks!

Comment: `\par \hrulefill\ EDUCATION \hrulefill\par `  might get you started

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\rule[0.5ex]{2em}{1pt} EDUCATION \xrfill[0.5ex]{1pt}    

\noindent   
\textbf{XXXCollege}, XXX, NY \hfill Aug 2015 -- May 2019

\begin{itemize}[nosep,topsep=0pt]
    \item Bachelor ...
    \item Concentration ...
    \item GPA ...
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I use the code as is though, I get a "Undefined control sequence". Had to change the line: 
`\rule[0.5ex]{2em}{1pt} EDUCATION \xhfill[0.5ex]{1pt}`    
to this: 
`... EDUCATION \xrfill[0.5ex]{1pt}`

Comment: Ah, yes, I changed the macro in my style file. Will edit my answer.